# Getting a token from an external web API is returning system.threading.tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, model-view-controller, bearer-token

I'm successfully getting a token back from my `GetAccessToken()` and `GetAccessTokenAsync` methods, but the token isn't retrieved until after the main method of `GetCourses`, which won't work because that's the method that collects the data I need to show on my cshtml page. I've tried pulling apart this controller and creating a Globals class that will house just the URIs, apiKey, and token, but then I read that's bad practice for `MVC` so I ditched that effort. It was getting called after the `GetCourses` method anyway, so it was dead end too.

I'm newer to MVC and come from a `WebForms` background where I was used to being able to throw this kind of code in my `PageInit`, but am struggling to figure out how to pull this off in `MVC`. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong or if I need to go about this a different way?

```
    public ActionResult GetCourses()
    {
        TempData["EthosURI"] = "redacted";
        TempData["Token"] = GetAccessToken().ToString();

        IEnumerable<Course> courses = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri((string)TempData["EthosURI"]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {" + (string)TempData["Token"] + "}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            //HTTP GET
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("courses");
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Course>>();
                readTask.Wait();

                courses = readTask.Result;
            }
            else //web api sent error response 
            {
                //log response status here..

                courses = Enumerable.Empty<Course>();
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
        }
        return View(courses);
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync("redactedUrl", "redactedAPIKey");
        return token;
    }
    public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string ethosURI, string apiKey)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ethosURI);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(ethosURI)
            };
            request.Headers.Clear();
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: even though you didn't postfix `GetAccessToken` with Async it's still an async method so you need to wait for it to complete. I would also advise to change your signature to `public async Task<ActionResult> GetCourses()` so you can `await` all calls that have `Task` or `Task<TResult>` as their return type.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `GetCourses()` method and am able to get the token back. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (non-blocking) way in C# to wait for a task to complete is to use the `await` keyword. And for a method to use the `await` keyword, it has to be marked `async`. By using `await`, you not only wait for the task to complete, but also the current thread is not blocked. Wrapping an asynchronous operation in another method would not make it synchronous. In other words, the asynchronous nature propagates up the call hierarchy and the caller has to await. So, the `GetAccessToken()` still has to be awaited.  A controller action can be marked asynchronous as well, so you probably want:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCourses()
{
    TempData["EthosURI"] = "redacted";
    TempData["Token"] =  (await GetAccessToken()).ToString(); // note the additional parentheses
   ....
```

Note the additional parantheses above before calling `ToString()`. However, since `GetAccessToken()` already returns a `string`, you don't need the redundant `ToString()` call:

```
TempData["Token"] =  await GetAccessToken();
```

Now, you can also change this:

```
var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Course>>();
readTask.Wait();
courses = readTask.Result;
```

to just:

```
courses = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Course>>();
```

Microsoft has quite good [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) on asynchronous programming and I would recommend checking it out.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you so much! That additional `GetAccessToken` method was my hope that I could figure out how to use an async task in a non-async method. I got rid of it and just have `GetCourses` and `GetAccessTokenAsync` now. I really appreciate the link too, I really need to soak this stuff up since APIs have been put on my plate now and aren't going anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how async works in C#. You need either to make `GetCourses()` `async` AND await for `GetAccessToken()`, or use dirty hack `GetAccessToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but it may become not safe in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `GetCourses()` method and am able to get the token back now. :)